# ConcurrentDictionary AddOrUpdate by predicate

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, concurrentdictionary

I have a `ConcurrentDictionary`. I use its `AddOrUpdate` method to manipulate its items.

My question is: is it possible to use `AddOrUpdate`'s update parameter to contain an if statement? E.g. my `ConcurrentDictionary` contains objects that has string Id and a DateTime Date properties.

I'd like to
- add a new object to it, if the object with the given Id does not exist
- update it, if the new object's Date is equal or greater, than the existing one, if it is less, than does not do anything.

In my example:

```
Dictionary.AddOrUpdate(testObject.Id,testObject,(k, v) => v);
```

I should change

```
(k, v) => v
```

to

```
if(v.Date >= existingItem.Date) (k, v) => v
else do nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v` is the value that currently exists in the collection, so to do nothing just return it.

```
Dictionary.AddOrUpdate(testObject.Id,testObject,(k, v) => 
    (v.Date >= existingItem.Date) ? testObject : v);
```

More readable:

```
Dictionary.AddOrUpdate(testObject.Id,testObject,(k, v) => 
{
    if(v.Date >= existingItem.Date) 
        return testObject; 
    else
        return v;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to achieve this would be for your `updateValueFactory` lambda to return the original value if the new value is not greater:

```
Dictionary.AddOrUpdate(testObject.Id, testObject,
    (key, value) => testObject.Date > value.Date ? testObject : value);
```